# A way to rotate the character to the corresponding inputs glm

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have been trying to rotate (and have a smooth rotation) the character to the corresponding user Inputs but I am always having a problem and i need to know how to solve it.Since the nonsmooth rotation worked I am trying to make one that is smooth.

The code I have used:

```
if (LeftKey == true)
{
        if (RightKey == true)
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 45;
        }
}
else
{
        if (RightKey == true)
        {
            PlayerOrientation = -45;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 0;
        }
    }
}
else if (RightKey == false && LeftKey == true)
{
    if (DownKey == true)
    {
        if (UpKey == true)
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 90;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 135;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (UpKey == true)
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 45;
        }  
        else
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 90;
        }
    }
}
else if (UpKey == false && DownKey == true)
{
    if (LeftKey == true)
    {
        if (RightKey == true)
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 180;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 135;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (RightKey == true)
        {
            PlayerOrientation = -135;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerOrientation = 180;
        }
    }
}
else if (LeftKey == false && RightKey == true)
{
    if (DownKey == true)
    {
        if (UpKey == true)
        {
            PlayerOrientation = -90;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerOrientation = -135;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (UpKey == true)
        {
            PlayerOrientation = -45;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerOrientation = -90;
        }
    }
}

if (UpKey == true || DownKey == true || RightKey == true || LeftKey == true)
{
    if (ThePlayerOrientation != PlayerOrientation)
    {
        float difference = (PlayerOrientation - ThePlayerOrientation) / 20;
        thePlayerPos += difference;

        if (PlayerOrientation == thePlayerPos)
        {
            ThePlayerOrientation = PlayerOrientation;
            thePlayerPos = PlayerOrientation;
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could help me it would be really helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but my understanding is that currently when you press a key, your character immediately rotates from 0 to 95 degrees to the right. To improve the rotation animation, you may want to consider setting a rotation speed of 90 degrees per second. Then, in each frame, calculate the time elapsed since the previous frame and add the corresponding degrees of rotation to your character's angle. I hope it answers, sorry if it isn't.
PS : xD didn't see you asked it 11 month ago